# how to validate foreign key column kendo inline grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui

I have inline editing grid which using foreign key column. In the foreignKey.cshtml i also add the option label ("Please select").

Views:

```
columns.ForeignKey(p => p.EmployeeID, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["testStatus"], "EmployeeID", "EmployeeName");
```

Model:

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
 [DisplayName("Employee ")]
 [UIHint("GridForeignKey")]
 public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
```

Shared/GridForeignKey.cshtml

```
@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))
        .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
        .OptionLabel("Select value")

)
```

My question is, how i can validate if the user choose "Please select" option and display required message. THank you

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the range attribute instead of required to the model. More than likely your first item is of "please select" is being given a value of 0 or "please select" so the required attribute won't do what you need since technically that input has a value.

```
[Range(1, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please Select A Value")]
public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
```

Also try add a selected index to your drop down list assuming you don't already have a selected value.

```
@(
 Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name(ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(""))
    .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
    .OptionLabel("Select value")
    .SelectedIndex(0)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the [Required] data annotation attribute to your Model property? If you have not, is there any difference?

Comment: yes, i did required data annotation attribute in model property. I suspect because as a default the select value option is selected.